# Understanding the timeline of The Flash Season 1

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014

I have lots of questions with *The Flash* Season 1. Can someone please help me understand the timeline of the first season?

This is what I understood. *This might be totally wrong.*

1. Eobard Thawne came from the future.

   a. Did he come from 2024? `The Flash vanishes in crisis 2024`.

   b. Did he come to kill the Flash or his mother?
2. Thawne kills Barry's mother. Barry's father goes to prison and Barry Allen goes to live with Joe West.
3. Thawne could not go back to his original timeline (because?). So he kills Harrison Wells and stays in the current timeline.
4. Thawne knew how to create The Flash! He worked at S.T.A.R. labs and planned the explosion of the particle accelerator (How did Thawne know how to create The Flash?)
   *How was the _original_ Flash created or, if Thawne had not traveled back in time, then how would The Flash have been created?*
5. Thawne needed to create The Flash so that he could go back to his original timeline.
6. Eddie Thawne was an ancestor of Eobard Thawne. Eddie kills himself to indirectly kill Eobard Thawne.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Eobard Thawne came from the future.**

Yes. However he came from a very distant future, not 2024. He came to kill *Nora Allen*, Barry's mother. Eobard became a speedster because of Barry, if he had killed Barry he wouldn't be a speedster. This also resulted in Barry's father being convicted for the murder.

**Thawne kills Barry's mother. Barry's father goes to prison and Barry Allen goes to live with Joe West.**

Yap, that's pretty much it. Barry was raised as Iris' brother and is seen as a son by Joe.

**Thawne could not go back to his original timeline (because?). So he kills Harrison Wells and stays in the current timeline.**

He screwed with the timeline. He has to make sure that Barry becomes The Flash in order for his future self to become the Reverse Flash. Furthermore at the time he was too weak to travel back to the future and planned on harnessing The Flash's speed to do so.

**Thawne knew how to create The Flash! He worked at S.T.A.R. labs and planned the explosion of the particle accelerator (How did Thawne know how to create The Flash?).

How was the *original* Flash created or, if Thawne had not traveled back in time, then how would The Flash have been created?**

The Flash was created by accident. The thing is, Eobard changed the world (he lived as Harrison Wells up till the late stages of Season 1). Eobard merely made Barry become the Flash sooner than it originally would've happened, and not a coincidence this time.

**Thawne needed to create The Flash so that he could go back to his original timeline.**

**Eddie Thawne was an ancestor of Eobard Thawne. Eddie kills himself to indirectly kill Eobard Thawne.**

Yes, that's the idea. However due to *wibbily wobbly timey wimey* stuff a version (or more) of past-Eobard were stuck in the timeline and were still alive after Eddie killed himself. One of such Eobards was the main antagonist on *Legends of Tomorrow - Season 2*

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Accepted. I still have lots of questions but I think those will need a long discussion. :)